# Managing External Assets in R Package

Tags: git, r

I am writing an R package called `slidify` which makes it easy to generate reproducible HTML5 slides from R Markdown files. The package makes use of `css` and `js` files from several existing HTML5 slide generation frameworks like `dzslides`, `deck.js` etc. Currently, I have organized the downloaded versions of these external assets in the `inst/libraries` folder of `slidify`, so that it is automatically available for users upon installation. While this approach is simple, there are some disadvantages:

1. These frameworks are constantly updated on `github`. Under the current setup, I would have to push a new version of the package everytime any of these frameworks are updated.
2. If I make any tweaks to the default `css` and `js` that come with these frameworks, then I need to merge the updates carefully so that I don't lose `slidify` specific customizations.

I had a couple of thoughts on how to manage this.

1. Don't package these libraries with `slidify`. Instead, provide a `function` that would allow users to add the frameworks they desire.
2. Add these frameworks to the `inst\libraries` folder on `slidify`, but as `submodules`. Now, I have no idea if adding them as `submodules` would get them installed if someone were to use `devtools::install_github`.

**So my question is, when writing an R package how can I manage external non-R dependencies which are updated constantly?**

Comment: I really like your question; tweaked the phrasing at the end to ward off "not constructive" votes.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. It makes the question cleaner.

Comment: One possibility is to look at packages `xlsx` and `XLConnect`. Both depend on Java libraries. `xlsx` defines (and depends on) a stand-alone package `xlsxjars` that only contains the libraries. In this way, the downstream code is decoupled from the libraries.

Comment: Freezing the version of the dependancies along with the version of the package seems like the safest way. In case one of the packages changes substancially then your package can still work without having to hurry massively to fix the broken dependancies. Also best not to overwrite the dependancy files but overload instead and load after the originals, makes things more manageable.

Comment: The dependencies are just `css` and `js` files that control the slides. So it does not affect the package code directly. These external packages are adding features constantly, and the idea to keep things updated is for users to take advantage of the bleeding edge features. But, I think the dependency idea make sense and for every release of `slidify`, I need to freeze specs so that there are no incompatibilities.

Comment: @Andrie can you post your comment as an answer. After quite some thought I realized that it is the most sensible thing to do and easiest to manage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One analogous situation is to look at the packages `xlsx` and `XLConnect`.

Both packages depend on Java libraries. `xlsx` defines (and depends on) a stand-alone package `xlsxjars` that only contains the libraries.

In this way, the downstream code is decoupled from the libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar issue by using `git-subtree`.  Have a look at: [Managing 3rd party sources and binaries used by code under source control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318738/managing-3rd-party-sources-and-binaries-used-by-code-under-source-control)