# Include 3rd party libraries in my git repository

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Managing 3rd party sources and binaries used by code under source control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318738/managing-3rd-party-sources-and-binaries-used-by-code-under-source-control)

What would be the problems to include 3rd party libraries in my git repository. 3rd party libraries like Doctrine. Is this a good idea or not? why?

Comment: This question belongs on programmers.se

Answer (score 3):

Maybe including it as a submodule (http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) is a slightly better idea.