# R Package with Large Size External Assets

Tags: r, package

This is a followup to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314342/managing-external-assets-in-r-package) I posted earlier. To summarize, I am writing an R Package called Slidify, which makes use of several external non-R based libraries. My earlier question was about how to manage dependencies.

Several solutions were proposed, of which the most attractive solution was to package the external libraries as a different R package, and make it a dependency for Slidify. This is the strategy followed by the package `xlsx`, which packages the java dependencies as a different package `xlsxjars`.

An alterative is for me to provide the external libraries as a download and package a `install_libraries` function within Slidify, which would automatically fetch the required files and download it into the package directory. I can also add an `update_libraries` function which would update if things change.

My question is, are there any specific advantages to doing the CRAN dance for external libraries which are not R based. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Don't do the `install_libraries` hack.  Using CRAN as a central repo and distribution mechanism is preferable: `install.packages()` already exists, as do the updating variants etc.  By reinventing a new mechanism you will simply go down a slippery slope of new and untested errors.  You are essentially trying to reinvent what a distro or a system like fink does.  Too much complexity.

Comment: Thanks for your comemnt @Dirk. The external libraries are 10MB in size and when I read CRAN documentation, it said something to the effect of keeping things below 5MB. I see your point that CRAN provides a simple mechanism and it makes sense to use it wherever possible.

Comment: Is it Java as for xlxs and weka?  Then a jars package makes sense. Else you have the issue of binary compatibility and may have to resort on relying on the user.

Comment: It is `javascripts` and `css`. It also includes a stripped down version of `mathjax` which comes to around 3.6MB.

Comment: Perfect -- static files, platform agnostic. I think the 'resource package' is your best bet.

Comment: By 'resource package' you are referring to packaging the dependencies separately as an R package right? Just want to make sure.

Comment: Yes  -- just as xlsx and weka do with their matching "resource" packages.  Thanks for doing slidify by the way.

Comment: @Dirk Perfect. I just created slidifyLibraries and set it up. This way I can separate development for the core R functions and the supporting libraries. Can you post your response as an answer so that I can accept it? Or I can synthesize your response and post an answer. Let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comment-thread, for a package like slidify with a number of large, (mostly) fixed, and portable files, a "resource" package makes more sense:

- you will know the path where it installed (as the package itself will tell you)
- users can't accidentally put it somewhere else
- you get CRAN tests
- you get CRAN distribution, mirrors, ...
- users already know `install.packages()` etc
- the more nimble development of your package *using* these fixed parts is not held back by the large support files

Comment: Thanks for posting a comprehensive answer @Dirk. The advantages that you describe in detail make a strong case for distributing even non-R resources via CRAN.

Comment: Maybe I take CRAN attitude over github smugness?  ;-)

Comment: Well we can have both :-), since users can install `slidifyLibraries` from `github` using `install_github` by @hadley .